# Как настроить редирект реферальных ссылок в htaccess?

Tags: php, linux, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Ссылки вида https://domain.com/partner/ref45, (цифры после ref могут быть разные), редиректить на https://domain.com/partner/index.php

При этом оставлять url первоначальный - https://domain.com/partner/ref45
Подскажите как это прописать в htaccess?

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте такой вариант, возможно в вашем случае нужны иные параметры редиректа `[R=301,NC,L]`

```
RewriteRule ^partner/ref([0-9]+)$ /partner/index.php [R=301,NC,L]
```

Посмотрите [здесь](https://help.dreamhost.com/hc/en-us/articles/215747748-How-can-I-redirect-and-rewrite-my-URLs-with-an-htaccess-file-), вероятно там есть для вас ответ

Answer (score 0):

Вот вариант "редиректа с сохранением первоначального url":

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/partner/ref\d+$
RewriteRule .* /partner/index.php [QSA,L]
```